# How conditional comparing string with boolean really works in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am curious about how the conditional comparing works in js regarding the boolean and string. For example:

```
console.log("true" > false)
//OUTPUT: false

console.log("true" >= false)
//OUTPUT: false
```

Assuming if it's false in the first lines of code, what happens in the second line of code? Why does it not returning true? I would be appreciated if any of you guys give me the general rule for these comparisons. I can understand equality, but not with those conditional comparison when comparing string and boolean.

Comment: Have a look a this: https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.8.5

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the resources